# PySpark - Add a new column with a Rank by User

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have this PySpark DataFrame

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.array([
    ["aa@gmail.com",2,3], ["aa@gmail.com",5,5],
    ["bb@gmail.com",8,2], ["cc@gmail.com",9,3]
]), columns=['user','movie','rating'])

sparkdf = sqlContext.createDataFrame(df, samplingRatio=0.1)
```

```
         user movie rating
aa@gmail.com     2      3
aa@gmail.com     5      5
bb@gmail.com     8      2
cc@gmail.com     9      3
```

I need to add a new column with a Rank by User

I want have this output

```
         user  movie rating  Rank
aa@gmail.com     2      3     1
aa@gmail.com     5      5     1
bb@gmail.com     8      2     2
cc@gmail.com     9      3     3
```

How can I do that?

Comment: So the goal here is to add consecutive integers based on `user` order?

Comment: Yes it is @zero323

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is really no elegant solution here as for now. If you have to you can  try something like this:

```
lookup = (sparkdf.select("user")
    .distinct()
    .orderBy("user")
    .rdd
    .zipWithIndex()
    .map(lambda x: x[0] + (x[1], ))
    .toDF(["user", "rank"]))

sparkdf.join(lookup, ["user"]).withColumn("rank", col("rank") + 1)
```

Window functions alternative is much more concise:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import dense_rank

sparkdf.withColumn("rank", dense_rank().over(w))
```

but it is extremely inefficient and **should be avoided in practice**.

Comment: Is there any references to why window functions should be avoided in practice?

Comment: @Oleksiy Rule of thumb -> No `partitionBy` clause or low cardinality of the partition key. I haven't checked how recent changes on master (2.0.0+)  affect that, but I am quite sure that not much.

Comment: @zero323 -thank you for the answer. Could you explain why it is inefficient and what three lines below do:     .zipWithIndex()
    .map(lambda x: x[0] + (x[1], ))
    .toDF(["user", "rank"]))