# PySpark RDD - get Rank, into JSON

Tags: json, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a Hive query that returns data as such:

```
Date,Name,Score1,Score2,Avg_Score
1/1/2018,A,10,20,15
1/1/2018,B,20,20,20
1/1/2018,C,15,10,12.5
1/1/2018,D,11,12,11.5
1/1/2018,E,21,29,25
1/1/2018,F,10,21,15.5
```

I use `hive_context.sql(my_query).rdd` to get this into an RDD.
My ultimate aim is to get this into a JSON format with descending rank based on Avg_score as follows:

```
Scores=
[
    {
        "Date": '1/1/2018',
        "Name": 'A',
        "Avg_Score": 15,
        "Rank":4
    },
    {
        "Date": '1/1/2018',
        "Name": 'B',
        "Avg_Score": 20,
        "Rank":2
    }
]
```

As a first step of getting ranks, I tried implementing [this approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46042749) but I keep running into errors like `AttributeError: 'RDD' object has no attribute 'withColumn'`

How would I get this done?

Comment: Have you tried not converting to `rdd` and operate on a DataFrame (`withColumn` is a DataFrame function)

Comment: @pault Not sure I understand your question - I already have the RDD

Comment: Try `df = hive_context.sql(my_query)` (remove the `.rdd`)

Comment: then you have this to convert your Dataframe to and RDD of dict https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49432167/convert-rows-into-dictionary-in-pyspark

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because your are working at the RDD level. You have to stay with a Dataset (or Dataframe) if you want to the use the Dataframe API. As mentionned in the comments to you question, you can remove the `.rdd` conversion and use `asDict` to get the final result.

```
df = sc.parallelize([
  ("1/1/2018","A",10,20,15.0),
  ("1/1/2018","B",20,20,20.0),
  ("1/1/2018","C",15,10,12.5),
  ("1/1/2018","D",11,12,11.5),
  ("1/1/2018","E",21,29,25.0),
  ("1/1/2018","F",10,21,15.5)]).toDF(["Date","Name","Score1","Score2","Avg_Score"])

from pyspark.sql import Window
import pyspark.sql.functions as psf

w = Window.orderBy(psf.desc("Avg_Score"))

rddDict = (df
  .withColumn("rank",psf.dense_rank().over(w))
  .drop("Score1","Score2")
  .rdd
  .map(lambda row: row.asDict()))
```

with the result

```
>>> rddDict.take(1)
[{'Date': u'1/1/2018', 'Avg_Score': 25, 'Name': u'E', 'rank': 1}]
```

Note however the warning with using a Window function with no partitioning:

```
18/08/13 11:44:32 WARN window.WindowExec: No Partition Defined for Window operation! Moving all data to a single partition, this can cause serious performance degradation.
```

Comment: Even if doesn't address specifically the order-conserving issue, this thread is an interesting and (partially) relevant read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30304810/dataframe-ified-zipwithindex